# LocalStorage not updating and then storing new values

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, local-storage

My goal is to build a large array of data that has both text and numbers, and the text is randomly selected from a preselected array of names (first and last name). Function start() is activated with a button.

```
var malenames = ["John", "Bob", "Jim","Tim","Skylar","Zach","Jacob"];
var maleLast = ["J.","M.","B.","D.","W."];
var males = new Array();
males[0] = new Array("Placeholder","Placeholder",18);
males[1] = new Array("Placeholder","Placeholder",18);
males[2] = new Array("Placeholder","Placeholder",18);
males[3] = new Array("Placeholder","Placeholder",18);
males[4] = new Array("Placeholder","Placeholder",18);
males[5] = new Array("Placeholder","Placeholder",18);
males[6] = new Array("Placeholder","Placeholder",18);
males[7] = new Array("Placeholder","Placeholder",18);
males[8] = new Array("Placeholder","Placeholder",18);
males[9] = new Array("Placeholder","Placeholder",18);




function start() {
localStorage.setItem("random", Math.floor((Math.random()*(100-0))));
span.textContent = localStorage.getItem("random");


var i;
var j;
for (i=0; i < males.length; i++) {
males[i][0] = malenames[Math.floor(Math.random()*malenames.length)];
localStorage.setItem("males", JSON.stringify(males));
}

for (j=0; j<males.length; j++) {
males[j][1] = maleLast[Math.floor(Math.random()*maleLast.length)];
localStorage.setItem("males", JSON.stringify(males));
}



firstN.textContent = males[0][0];
lastN.textContent = males[0][1];
age.textContent = males[0][2];

}
```

This code successfully randomizes and then saves the first and last names into the array in localStorage. However, I am wanting to modify the number 18 on a timer by adding a value to it every so many seconds.

```
setInterval(function(){

var k;

for(k=0;k<males.length;k++){

males[k][2]++;
localStorage.setItem("males",JSON.stringify(males));


}
age.innerHTML = males[0][2];

}, 3000);
```

Everything works just fine and everything gets stored into localStorage until I refresh the page. When I refresh the page, the localStorage array is still correct until the interval occurs. When this happens, the arrays refresh back to [Placeholder, Placeholder, 18]. I am curious as to why the code does this when I am only trying to add to the age variable every interval. I would gladly accept feedback and explanations into understanding this. Thank you.

Comment: You need to use more logic when developing your code. `localStorage.setItem("males",JSON.stringify(males));` is inside a loop? Why? I guess we should start by asking what you're really trying to do, so we can show you a more logical approach.

Comment: @StackSlave well, the thing that you are pointing out doesn't seem to be my biggest issue because it works as it is when storing and then displaying the names, so your point seems irrelevant to my bigger issues. My problem is in dealing with the setInterval part. When the setInterval code activates after a browser refresh, the localStorage data in the "males" array restarts to the default [Placeholder, Placeholder, 18], but it works otherwise (no refreshing).

Comment: It looks like your males is not based on the localStorage when you rerun your mess. `var males = localStorage.males; if(!males){ /* run your start code */ }`.

Comment: @StackSlave why is everyone so pretentious on this website, how is it that bad of a mess? lmao anyhow, you are incorrect because if that were the case, it would not save the names when I delete the setInterval code. When I delete the setInterval code, the names are perfectly stored in localStorage even after refreshing the browser. So obviously there is something wrong with the setInterval code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you really want to do something more like:

```js
function shuffle(a){
  a.sort(function(b, c){
    return 0.5 - Math.random();
  });
}
function RandomPeople(lastNameArray, firstNameArray){
  var t = this;
  this.lastNames; this.firstNames;
  this.make = function(){
    this.lastNames = lastNameArray.slice(); this.firstNames = firstNameArray.slice();
    this.people = []; shuffle(this.firstNames);
    this.firstNames.forEach(function(n){
      t.people.push([t.lastNames[Math.floor(Math.random()*t.lastNames.length)], n, 18]);
    });
    return this;
  }
  this.grab = function(){
    if(localStorage.people){
      return JSON.parse(localStorage.people);
    }
    return false;
  }
  this.save = function(){
    localStorage.people = JSON.stringify(this.people);
    return this;
  }
}
var men = new RandomPeople(['J.', 'M.', 'B.', 'D.', 'W.'], ['John', 'Bob', 'Jim', 'Tim', 'Skylar', 'Zach', 'Jacob']);
var peps = men.grab();
if(!peps){
  men.make(); peps[5][2] += 2; men.save(); peps = men.people;
}
console.log(peps);
```